# How can this property of the inverse of a matrix exponential be proven?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrix-exponential

The following is an excerpt from a book I'm reading:

> The following property of the matrix exponential can readily be established by a variety of methods-the easiest perhaps being the use of the series definition (3.4)-
> \begin{equation} \tag{3.8}
> e^{A(t_1 + t_2)} = e^{At_1}e^{At_2}
> \end{equation}
> for any $t_1$ and $t_2$. From this property, it follows that
> \begin{equation} \tag{3.9}
> \left(e^{A\tau}\right)^{-1} = e^{-A\tau}
> \end{equation}

How does $(3.9)$ follow from $(3.8)$?

Comment: Hint: Take $t_1=\tau$ and $t_2=-\tau$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that the matrix $B$ is the inverse of the (square) matrix $C$ if and only if $CB = I$, and its the notational convention to call the matrix $B$ which solves this $C^{-1}$.

So for the matrix $C = e^{A\tau}$, its inverse $(e^{A\tau})^{-1}$ is the matrix $B$ such that
$$e^{A\tau}B = I.$$

From (3.8) we have
$$ e^{A\tau}e^{-A\tau}=e^{A(\tau + (-\tau))} = e^{A0} = I$$
which shows that the matrix $B = e^{-A\tau}$ is the inverse of $e^{A\tau}$, that is $(e^{A\tau})^{-1} = e^{-A\tau}$.